# Show that every open cover of the unit sphere $|x|=1$ in $\mathbb R^N$ also covers an annulus $1-\delta\leq|x|\leq1+\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that, if $S(0,1) \subset \bigcup\limits_{\lambda\in L}A_{\lambda}$ for an open cover $(A_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}$, there is $\delta>0$ so that $\bigcup\limits_{\lambda\in L}A_{\lambda}$ covers $K = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N \,|\, (1-\delta)^2 \leq |x|^2 \leq (1 + \delta)^2\}$.

So I took $\delta$ in the following way.

$\exists\epsilon>0$, such as $B(a,\epsilon)\subset \cup_{\lambda\in L}A_{\lambda}$, then $\delta = \inf\{\epsilon_a \,|\, B(a,\epsilon_a)\subset \bigcup_{\lambda\in L}A_{\lambda}, a\in S(0,1)\}$

Then I know that I must show $x\in K \Rightarrow x\in \cup_{\lambda\in L}A_{\lambda}$

but I'm stuck. Any help?

Comment: What is $S(0,1)$?

Comment: It is the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Comment: @BrunoMazeto. If i got it right ,you ask if an open cover of $S^{n-1}$ can  also cover  a sphere of thickness $2 \delta$?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. The title was confusing. Thank you for the editing

Answer (score 2):

My hint for what you are struggling with goes as follows: let $d(\cdot)$ be the standard Euclidean metric, i.e. $d(\alpha,\beta)=|\alpha-\beta|$.  Then, by the triangle inequality, $d(x,0)\leq d(x,a)+d(a,0)=d(x,a)+1$, and by the reverse triangle inequality, $d(x,a)\geq|d(a,0)-d(x,a)|=|1-d(x,a)|$.

But there is a bigger problem with your partial solution: your choice of $\delta$.  How do you know that your $\delta>0$?   You may want to note that $S^{n-1}$ is compact.

Comment: I know $\delta$ is positive because it is the infimum of all positive $\epsilon$. One could choose it differently, I chose that way, because it was a hint.

Comment: You applied the hint too early. The infimum of a set of positive number is a limit point of $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{0\}$. After all, what is the infimum of $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\mathbb{Z}^+\}$?) On the other hand, the *minimum* of a *finite* set of a positive number is in that set, hence positive. Hopefully, this hints why you might need compactness.

Answer (score 2):

It is essential that the unit sphere $S\subset{\mathbb R}^N$ is compact. Define a function
$f:\>S\to{\mathbb R}_{>0}$ by
$$f(x):=\sup\bigl\{\delta>0\bigm|\exists \lambda\in L: \ B_\delta(x)\subset A_\lambda\bigr\}\qquad(x\in S)\ .$$
*Claim:* This $f$ is continuous.

*Proof.* Consider a point $x\in S$ and assume $B_\delta(x)\subset A_\lambda$. If $x'$ is a nearby point on $S$ then the triangle inequality implies
$$B_{\delta-|x'-x|}(x')\subset B_\delta(x)\subset A_\lambda\ .$$
Since we can find such an $A_\lambda$ for all $\delta<f(x)$ this implies that $f(x')\geq f(x)-|x'-x|$. This shows that $f$ is even Lipschitz continuous.$\qquad\square$

Since $S$ is compact the function $f$ assumes a positive minimum $\mu$ on $S$. Putting $\delta:={\mu\over2}$ ensures the  claim in the question.

Comment: I still don't understand the $f(x')\geq f(x)−|x'−x|$. If $\delta < f(x)$ and $\delta '<f(x')$, isn't it the opposite, I mean, $f(x)-f(x')\geq |x-x'|$?

Comment: @BrunoMazeto: From the $A_\lambda$ used to compute $f(x)$ alone we can conclude that $f(x')$ satisfies the stated inequality. But there might be other $A_\lambda$s near $x'$ that make $f(x')$ even greater.